# Change the increase value of numericupdown

Tags: vb.net, winforms, numericupdown

I am looking for a while how to change the increase value of `numericupdown` in vb.net and can't find any resources online.

What I mean is, when you have a `numericupdown` with value 1,000 and minimum of 0, maximum of 100,000, I want to make it when someone clicks the increase arrow, the value to increase by 1,000 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the minimum and maximum values like this:

```
Me.NumericUpDown1.Minimum = 0
Me.NumericUpDown1.Maximum = 100000
```

You can define the increment like this:

```
Me.NumericUpDown1.Increment = 1000
```